# Deployed Cloud Function runs but does not modify BigQuery table?

Tags: python, automation, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am a complete beginner in using GCP functions/products. I have written the following code below, that takes a list of cities from a local folder, and call in weather data for each city in that list, eventually uploading those weather values into a table in BigQuery.

```
import requests, datetime, re
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

def weather_inserting(data, context):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("weather_api_ipro")
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs("weather_api_ipro")
    blob = bucket.blob("list_of_cities.txt")
    cities = blob.download_as_string()
    cities = cities.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    list_city = cities.split("\r\n")
    del list_city[-1]

    API_key = "PLACEHOLDER"
    Base_URL = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/history.json?key="

    yday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    Date = yday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    table_id = f"sonic-cat-315013.weather_data.Historical_Weather_testing"
    try:
        schema = [
            bigquery.SchemaField("city", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Date", "Date", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Hour", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Temperature", "FLOAT", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Humidity", "FLOAT", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Condition", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Chance_of_rain", "FLOAT", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Precipitation_mm", "FLOAT", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Cloud_coverage", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Visibility_km", "FLOAT", mode="REQUIRED")
        ]
        table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
        table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
            type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
            field="Date",  # name of column to use for partitioning
        )
        table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
        print(
            "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
        )
    except:
        print("Table {}_{} already exists".format(yday.isocalendar()[0], yday.isocalendar()[1]))

    
    k = 0
    while k < len(list_city):
        try:
            global city_name
            city_name = list_city[k]
            complete_URL = Base_URL + API_key + "&q=" + city_name + "&dt=" + Date
            response = requests.get(complete_URL, timeout = 10)
            x = response.json()
            try:
                x["location"]
            except:
                print(f"API could not call city {city_name}")

            global day, time, dailytemp, dailyhum, dailycond, chance_rain, Precipitation, Cloud_coverage, Visibility_km    

            day = []
            time = []
            dailytemp = []
            dailyhum = []
            dailycond = []
            chance_rain = []
            Precipitation = []
            Cloud_coverage = []
            Visibility_km = []

            for i in range(24):
                dayval = re.search("^\S*\s" ,x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["time"])
                timeval = re.search("\s(.*)" ,x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["time"])

                day.append(dayval.group()[:-1])
                time.append(timeval.group()[1:])
                dailytemp.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["temp_c"])
                dailyhum.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["humidity"])
                dailycond.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["condition"]["text"])
                chance_rain.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["chance_of_rain"])
                Precipitation.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["precip_mm"])
                Cloud_coverage.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["cloud"])
                Visibility_km.append(x["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"][i]["vis_km"])
            for h in range(len(time)):
                time[h] = int(time[h][:2])

            table = client.get_table(table_id)
            varlist = []
            for j in range(24):
                variables = city_name, day[j], time[j], dailytemp[j], dailyhum[j], dailycond[j], chance_rain[j], Precipitation[j], Cloud_coverage[j], Visibility_km[j]
                varlist.append(variables)
                
            client.insert_rows(table, varlist)
            print(f"City {city_name}, ({k+1} out of {len(list_city)}) successfully inserted")
            k += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

I have managed figuring out deploying the script in Cloud Functions with the help of some people here and going through others' questions. The function actually runs now without any errors or bugs coming up in the logs, it also prints out the successful

```
print(f"City {city_name}, ({k+1} out of {len(list_city)}) successfully inserted")
```

messages, but the BigQuery table is not modified/updated. I am not sure what to do, anybody have a suggestion? When I run the same code locally (except locally I authenticate the connection to the GCP project) in Jupyter Notebook, it works without an issue.

Comment: Can you check what the `client.insert_rows(table, varlist)` returns? I witnessed a strange behaviour when calling the `client.insert_rows_json`: when an error occurred, it did not raise an exception but returned a list with the errors messages. This might give you some debugging information why no row is inserted.

Comment: How do you check if the data are inserted or not? Do you use the preview feature or do you query the table?

Comment: So I checked both in Cloud Functions and locally, both return and empty list. Difference the two is that the locally run function actually fills the BigQuery table in, while the former doesn't.

Yes, I query the table.